# TS branded string as key of the object

Tags: typescript, static-typing

Imagine, that I have class Foo with string identifier.

```js
class Foo {
    id = '123' as FooId;
}
```

I try to ensure static typing of it using [a brand enum](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/tips/nominalTyping.html).

```js
enum FooIdBranding {}
type FooId = string & FooIdBranding;
```

So now, my goal is specific object, where the key is `FooId` and the value is `Foo`.

```js
type fooCache = { [key: FooId]: Foo };
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work:

> TS1023: An index signature parameter type must be 'string' or 'number'

I thought, that the [Record](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) is my solution, but is doesn't work too.

```js
type FooCache = Record<FooId, Foo>;

({} as FooCache)['123' as FooId] = new Foo();
```

> TS 7017: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type `Record<FooId, Foo>` has no index signature

Is there a correct way in TypeScript to resolve this problem?

Comment: Not possible at the moment, typescript forces idnex parameter to be `number` or `string` not even a union of that will do. Work is beeign done in this area, not sure if this exact scenario will be supported: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26797

Comment: Are there any workarounds?

Comment: Depends how far you want to go with lying to the compiler.. this will enforce the restrictions you want: https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/KYOwrgtgBAYg9nAkgEwEICcCGJkEsQDmUA3gL4BQALgJ4AOwsCKUAvFDfXAGZRgDWAbnIBjADaYAzhMZwSFDg3hwAwpmEALBmwBKwYXHTIAPAu68+AGhkA+Icj3j0DfSAmVzALl4hcARzAMEtQQAEZwokIAFGRQkjKqGsAAlADaAOQAjABMAMxpsdLY1AUyKAC6rFAgwADuMpFJUTFxSgmaqZm5aRVs1XVKDQJQAPTDUMDo6OTk9mKYTlAubuZZXmA+-oHBYRHTQA

Comment: Looks dynamically =) It feels, like using `Map<FooId, Foo>` is now the best way

Comment: It's still using strings .. it just lies to the compiler that the object is only indexable by the unique symbol .. it does the job but is a bit  hackish ..

Comment: No, it doesn't use string and it allows you to use even [real objects](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20IKey%20%7B%20key%3A%20string%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20aKey%20%3D%20%7B%20key%3A%20'aKey'%20%7D%20as%20IKey%3B%0D%0Aconst%20bKey%20%3D%20%7B%20key%3A%20'bKey'%20%7D%20as%20IKey%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20map%20%3D%20new%20Map%3CIKey%2C%20string%3E()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Amap.set(aKey%2C%20'a')%3B%0D%0Amap.set(bKey%2C%20'b')%3B)

Comment: And here is [with branding](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Foo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20id%20%3D%20'123'%20as%20FooId%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aenum%20FooIdBranding%20%7B%7D%0D%0Atype%20FooId%20%3D%20string%20%26%20FooIdBranding%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20fooCache%20%3D%20new%20Map%3CFooId%2C%20Foo%3E()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0AfooCache.set('123'%20as%20FooId%2C%20new%20Foo())%3B%0D%0AfooCache.set('123'%2C%20new%20Foo())%3B)

Answer (score 3):

["Symbol and Template String Pattern Index Signatures" were added to TypeScript 4.4](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-4/#symbol-template-signatures), so this is now possible.

```ts
type FooId = string & {brand: 'FooId'};
const id1 = '1' as FooId
const id2 = '2' as FooId

class Foo {
  constructor(public id: FooId) {}
}

type fooCache = { [key: FooId]: Foo };

const foo: fooCache = {
  // Type '{ key: Foo; }' is not assignable to type 'fooCache'.
  // Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'key' does not exist in type 'fooCache'.(2322)
  // (property) key: Foo
  key: new Foo(id1)
}

// All good
const bar: fooCache = {
  [id1]: new Foo(id1)
}
```

[Example in the TS playground.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nAkgEygXigZ2AJwJYB2A5lAGRQDeARjgIYHIBcUA5PEsiwL4DcAsACgAxnALYoeZAEZ0rKSyi1MsBCkEixwCcgBMsljoVKVHQeoA2S5e0qCoUDdhwBXIcDg4AFGGdVzeIW1mdhQASkouQUiBQVBIKAAzBABhWiEAC2gMCigAbQBrCBBg1WQAXRK4KF4zYVFxJLhmRtSMrNsBewB6LqgAeSoAKwg3KH9gCDpzKABbWhAoUXMFzEghPASF-II4AHcCKDAcOEgcYDwITAAaRQZWQpAFZDhLqB2tCAAPPHFCKDjoCwWmlMiw7FAHswCBBdiZPJIpKEorUelAAILmaZEBCodxwdT1LRUWg4ZopEHtCjg3IIipvGFwhFIgRcIA)